# Who said postmodernism is a Right-wing philosophy?

Tags: political-philosophy, postmodernism

The vast majority of texts I've read (probably all of them) link postmodernism with the Left-wing in politics. However, postmodernism attacks modern science, which was/is the main force against conservative monotheistic organized religion; postmodernism promotes individuality ("each one has its own truth"), undermining the idea of "Unity makes strength", a Left motto; postmodernist texts are - as a rule - very hard to understand, thus elitist, the very opposite of Left classics, such as Bertolt Brecht or Noam Chomsky.

What are the published philosophers who wrote that postmodernism is a Right-wing philosophy?

Comment: I think you should read up more about postmodernism... Not only is it not a unified body of work, many people we would want to call postmodernists would disagree with your characterization of their work. Try [this](http://www.bruno-latour.fr/sites/default/files/70-DO-YOU-BELIEVE-IN-REALITY-GB.pdf).

Comment: This is an excellent observation you have made. I noticed a short post on another postmodern thread you made, and I immediately upvoted you. I don't know whether the right (or left) cooked up postmodernism intentionally or not. But it certainly makes the masses stupid. As the Marxian scholar Maximilien Rubel said, it stupefies them. Like shocking a deer with headlights.

Comment: Once the masses are dumbed down, literally stunned into immobility because they have no firm ground on which to stand on, the powers that be can do what they will. People need a least some firm ground. Why? Because life is short.  Mankind does not have time to endlessly ring its hands. Decisions are called for.

Comment: @Canyon Sorry, I did not mean to "slight" Canyon with my remarks. It sounds like she/he is really up to date on postmodernism and I do not want to remotely suggest that she is wrong. My personal interests lie in the area of what effect postmodernism has on the "masses" considering that the human lifespan is limited.

Comment: Poststructuralist dissolution of the subject and rejection of all forms of order as oppressive can be equally utilized by the left and by the right. French [Nouvelle Droite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nouvelle_Droite) (New Right) goes back to 1960-s, just as the New Left, and it was led by a philosopher too, Benoist, see [his interview](http://ihr.org/jhr/v14/v14n2p28_Warren.html). Ironically, their tactics were inspired by Gramsci, Italian Marxist. They are active in Le Pen's National Front and influenced American alt-right.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63776/discussion-on-question-by-rodrigo-who-said-postmodernism-is-a-right-wing-philoso).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real answer to the question it would help to know French. Then you would go to Paris and try to find a Parisian of the age of 75 or over  who was involved in the philosophcal-political "scene" of the 60s through 70s in Paris,  and they might be able to tell you the real story. Failing that you might do some research in a French library while you were there.  I am serious. This is the best way IMO. But difficult and not cheap!

Leo Loewenthal (Frankfurt School) made a few comments about it. George Lukacs wrote something on it I think, not much. Habermas. But these are not Frenchmen.   The Marxian, and more open, writers have addressed your question. You are not alone in realizing this phenomenon. However, most of their remarks are not in depth. Sometimes you run across something in an interview transcript, but again it is not addressed in depth.

Keep in mind, the volume of Marxian books,writers, philosophers went down after 1979, particularly in America, and in Europe too.

The other thing is to look for dissertations (PhD.) On the subject, but avoid cultural studies and literary studies dissertations, because generally they are worthless for philosophers. Historians and French studies majors can be good,philosophers would be best. You may look through a really good research library for more current books. I am out of date myself. Look for books by philosophers. Also Journals in philosophy, French studies, intellectual history if you have access to journals.  Oh, I forgot, Marxist, socialist journals, etc.

And of course, someone may come along here who can give you a good answer and good reference material!! But good references, really,  really good studies, are hard to find which address your exact question, at least in my experience.   You might have to write the book yourself.

PS. I think you will find that the earliest originators of postmodernism were "conservative". However, saying that does not capture the full flavor of Paris during this time. A person might switch from being a socialist to being conservative in one week's time, or he may have a string of ideologies at the end of his name.

Comment: I don't need in depth comments (I'd love to, though). But I'd love to have more specific references.

Comment: You're the kind of person I'd love to talk with in detail. But this is not a "safe" environment. Any alternative?

Comment: Yes, I suspected that.

Comment: I see. No alternatives. And most people here still probably think that "the West is the Best", and nowhere else we would have so much "freedom of expression".