# What are the relations between Neoliberalism and Postmodernism?

Tags: political-philosophy, postmodernism, politics

The [following passage](http://hipporeads.com/the-perverse-art-of-destroying-meaning/) surprised me, not only because it has `neoliberals` in place of `postmodernists`, but also because it describes everything I see as a consequence of so-called "Postmodernism" (or whatever name you give it: post-structuralism, deconstructionism, moral relativism...): destruction of meaning, praise of fragmentation, anti-intellectualism...

> Neoliberals are part of a long, intellectual, (or anti-intellectual)
>   tradition which seeks to deny the importance of meaning and even
>   destroy its relevance. Why would anyone want to do that? Because, as
>   history shows, destroying meaning is the key to gaining, at least
>   temporarily, power and control, whether it be over other human beings
>   or natural processes in general. For example, in his brilliant book on
>   the history of debt, David Graeber reveals how different forms of
>   slavery succeed by displacing people from their meaning-rich contexts.
>   As well as the application of brute force, people are rendered
>   powerless through being dislocated, fragmented, and thus, disoriented.
>   Those held in slavery have often survived by eventually creating new
>   systems of meaning, often through embracing religion of some form as a
>   way of transcending the power of their oppressors.

What are the relations between Postmodernism and Neoliberalism?

Comment: may be worth noting that fragmentation is a feature of modern life and literature.

Comment: too chatty, but have you considered the idea that "post modernist" is what happens to someone when they've been cheated out of something better? Ever get the feeling you've been cheated? Good night! * At the end of the last Sex Pistols concert, Winterland Theater, San Francisco, California (14 January 1978)[

Comment: You posit that in this paragraph "neoliberals" actually means "postmodernists", and then ask why this is so? </snark>

Comment: @user3293056 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postmodern_literature#Fragmentation

Comment: @mart I posit that they looked like actual synonyms in this sentence. So I ask if there are any other known relations. Why do I have to repeat the obvious?

Comment: [Zamora's take on Foucault](https://www.jacobinmag.com/2014/12/foucault-interview/) is the only direct relationship I know of, and it's had a pretty mixed reception.

Comment: i don't mean exclusively!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm the wrong person to answer your question because my gounding in philosophy is not that great, maybe I'm the right one because I likely share some of your political outlook ...

One of the posits of postmodernist thought is, I believe, that nothing has meaning per se, meaning is always assigned, negotiated etc. And so meaning can be destroyed. And this was always so, postmodernists and their forerunners are just the ones pointing this out instead of making up complicated metaphysic systems to safe a concept of meaning.

So neoliberals are just recent thinkers in a long line who tried to restructure society by, among other things, destroying systems of meaning and belonging - or solidarity! - that get in their way. As mentioned in the paragraph, this destruction of meaning was practiced millenia before Nietzsche wrote the first text that inspired Focault that inspired Deleuze or whomever.

One could also point out that certain systems of belonging, e.g. the specific nationalism of the Nazis to take the least controversial example, should be destroyed.

You could also ask what "meaning" in the context given above is supposed to mean (no pun intended), if it's not the meaning we give to things in a given moment, shaped by our experiences and thus pretty malleable.

Comment: Nice answer. But since postmodernism tries to destroy every big meaning (e.g. religion, science...), we end up in a dispute between those who have the infrastructure (the powerful) against those who haven't (the people). Guess who will be victorious? That's why destroying Nazis' nationalism don't actually balance things out.

Comment: I think "postmodernism tries to destroy every big meaning" is at best inaccurate - what exactly is there to destroy, what does destruction of meaning actually mean? Sorry I can't put it much more clear than this or my lase paragraph!

Comment: Confession? this was too dense for me, maybe you can make more of it: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/postmodernism/

Comment: In a Brazilian Federal University, my teachers were stating that science is "just another metanarrative, just as valid as any other", that is, they ignored completely what is the scientific method and how it works. They accused "modern science" of being "deterministic" when it actually is probabilistic. They said "everything is knowledge", can you believe it? That's what I call "destruction of meaning". The texts were all incredibly poorly written, most of them from the supposed Leftist *Boaventura de Sousa Santos*, which repeated all the vices attributed to postmodernists. Is this enough?

Comment: ... this walking cliche of a postmodernist you've ahs as a teacher does not bring us closer to what Graeber means with meaning in your quote above. If it can be destroyed, what is it in the first place?

Comment: I've also tried to answer your other question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/45429/3391 btw, dunno if helpful.

Comment: What is it in the first place? Science has a way of working, a method. Its meaning, how much we can trust it, is derived from the way it works. If a postmodernist says "it is *the same* as religion", then he/she is destroying that meaning. And Boaventura is, unfortunately, respected by the Left here, who just don't seem to see the disgrace he is doing. So it's not only that my teachers were "walking cliches", the problem lies in that thousands of such cliches are ruining the education of millions of students worldwide. And almost nobody seems to worry about it. At least not on this site.

Comment: ... and this is pretty far removed from your question about neolieralism which I tried to answer.

Comment: It may be. But you asked me about the meaning of "destruction of meaning". I was only answering your question. I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

Neoliberalism and Postmodernity are inversely related. Both follow what might be called high Modernism, which constituted a set of postwar institutions, values, and assumptions.

Among these were the concepts of the unity of the sciences, technological progress, abstraction in art, the Bretton Woods Accord and the United Nations, mass infrastructure, functionalist architecture, the welfare state, and a globalist outlook. At the same time, however, this unitary view was starkly divided by the the existence of conflicting economic systems in the so-called communist and capitalist realms. Not monotheism, but manicheanism.

In the developed Western nations, the situation produced the "managerial state" stabilizing welfare, Keynesian policies, large-scale public corporations, and broad labor union agreements--all meant to ameliorate the excesses and periodic collapses of capitalism. The Neoliberal revolution grew out of a reaction to inflation, along with a self-conscious conservative-capitalist "revolt." With the decline of state communism, the Neoliberal orthodoxy spread through global deregulation, debt financing, shareholder value, and a positivist, pseudoscientific view of "market pricing" as the sole calculus of value.

While this Thatcher-Reagan-Friedman dogma might claim to be type of social pluralism arising through deregulation and market "freedom," it was in fact a highly idealistic, financially centralized, globally aggressive hegemony imposed upon the world often through violent means. The author you quote seems to be making the point that such "postmodern" economics destroys local values, traditions, cultures, etc. through global finance and rampant commodification.

In a kind of dialectic inversion, this market utopianism gave rise to the various cultural trends loosely called Postmodernism, first in architecture. These are characterized by a skeptical pluralism and critique of the "grand narratives" or "gods-eye-view" of Modernism. The unity of the sciences, for example, could not be naively sustained amid increasing scientific specialization and more attention to the history and actual working methods of scientists. A certain relativism, for better or worse, becomes inevitable with the sheer accumulation of information.

The "inverse relation" I refer to is really the continuing dynamic of capitalism, which at one level unifies mass markets and concentrates wealth, while at another level accelerates the diversification of commodities and the "division of labor," including such cultural labors as science and art. This is undoubtedly an impetus to the various Postmodern trends. The mass-market destruction of local cultures, traditions, architectures, languages, species, and so forth likewise lends urgency to a pluralistic and preservationist reaction.

If you are interested, the geographer David Harvey has written a number of influential critiques of both Neoliberalism and Postmodernism from a Marxist perspective. While Neoliberalism is an active and well-defined ideological program, Postmodernism is more of a set of trends and critiques marked by its skepticism towards such one-size-fits-all programs.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. On the other hand, when Postmodernism fragments sense (by attacking every "grand narrative"), it is in fact scattering and weakening the Left, giving power to the already powerful capitalist Right. So I don't see them as "inversely related" in practice, though they may be so in discourse.

Comment: Yes, I would agree that the left has been weakened by the "liberal" turn away from labor economics to culture and identity politics. Postmodernism provides cover for many rightwing impulses, though I tend to see it as more descriptive than prescriptive.  But there is no doubt that both Putin and Trump are the crude practitioners of a postmodernist and post-truth politics.

Comment: Indeed. I see them using a technique that could be described as descriptive/prescriptive: mix two meanings of the verb to be (in Portuguese: ser/estar), i.e. somethings that are "constant" they describe as "transitory" and vice-versa. Sometimes they describe something and it isn't clear if they're denouncing or proposing. They're dishonest in many different ways.

Answer (score 1):

To the degree it proceeds along the same trajectory at all, Neoliberalism here is a step far before Postmodernism.  It is the embodiment of Enlightenment thinking in a wish to make more and more dependent upon less and less so that we are all 'free' from one another and from the harsher demands of our reality.  It is primarily an economic theory that reduces everything to market forces and freedom.  In that, it has a lot more to do with Existentialism than Postmodernism.

As 'The Genealogy of Morals' or Marxism points out, this war of the powerful constantly undermining the previous means of being powerful has been going on forever.  And it is wholly unrelated to the ultimate loss of the modernist dream to its own logic.

Neoliberalism is totally consonant with late modernism -- taking science and individuality as the center of the universe and rendering it cold, sterile, independent and unattached to any deeper meaning.  This attempt to make the universe rational and efficient is the ascending direction of the 'modernism' that Postmodernism questions.  It is part of what Postmodernism actually resists, by emphasizing context and admitting the relevance of the aspects of reality that we cannot know.

Displacing someone from their cultural embedding as a strategy for power, by controverting their religion with science and displacing their cultural institutions with your own, or with your own rational constructions, does not assume a respectful and constructive relativism.  It assumes that relativism is *wrong* and that dedication to institutions that are not entirely modern and rational is primitive and wasteful.  It seeks to leverage that 'waste' for 'good', without realizing that 'good' is selfishly defined and is itself something wasteful of what is embodied in traditions themselves over time.

Comment: You're ignoring that real dialogue is able to settle controversies, as long as neither side is fundamentalist. But since monotheism is essentially fundamentalist, it makes most Westerners believe that "real dialogue" is utterly impossible, like posited by postmodern religion.

Comment: This says nothing about the power of 'real dialog' one way or the other.  So you are putting words in my mouth.  I am sick of this.  I do not find that what you consider dialog takes place in good faith, and I am uninterested in continuing to accept your polemic.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but that's ok...

First, let's be clear: postmodernism (as such) does not exist, except in certain branches of aesthetics (fine art, architecture, perhaps literature...). The term 'postmodern' (when used by people talking about social theory or political philosophy) is something between a straw-man and a bogieman: it takes a wide variety of acute and painful social critiques and lumps them under a disparaging term where they can be blown off as occult reasoning. Anyone who uses the term 'postmodernist' in his way treats it as synonymous with pretentious, overblown, and sloppy thinking. And while there are clearly pretentious, overblown, and sloppy thinkers out there in the world — I've read a few myself — every craft has its share of poor craftsmen. We don't judge fine art by the holdings of [MOBA](http://museumofbadart.org), and we don't judge modern philosophy by the work of those who habitually trip over their own egos.

That said, neoliberalism is anti-philosophical and anti-intellectual, but that doesn't imply that they are trying to 'destroy meaning'. Neoliberals actually do the opposite: they try to construct and maintain a carefully husbanded worldview, so that people will return to the understandings of the world which allowed neoliberals to become powerful and wealthy. That isn't quite as crass as it sounds; I suspect most neoliberals honestly believe that worldview to be righteous and good. But the fact is that they are trying to *construct* a set of meanings which *ipso facto* implies the effort to destroy other worldviews and meaning-sets.

The kinds of things that get lumped derisively under the term 'postmodernism' are explicitly intellectual and philosophical. They are all, in their distinct ways, part of the protracted effort to uproot and dispose of the fancies and fabrications found in neoliberalism and other *status quo* ideologies. If neoliberalism tries to build a great dam that constrains and holds meaning within a circumscribed, defined comfort zone, these philosophical movements try to tear pieces of that dam down: to free up meaning, as it were. Neither project is explicitly nihilistic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127743/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-what-are-the-relations-between-neoliberalism).

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking You moved all the comments, not just the ones that composed a conversation between two people. Some comments pointed out genuine problems with this answer that would improve it. These, by policy, should be allowed.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: you should probably return the first three comments, and leave the discussion between me and gonzo over in chat (or delete it entirely; the whole thing seems to be predicated on bad feelings towards me personally).

Comment: I have no Bad feelings against you personally, Ted.  I know only the answers you have posted and the manner in which you respond to comments such as @Just Some Old Man,'s that "This answer greatly disregards the explicit and proud facetiousness postmodernists not just defended, but flaunted. It’s not straw-manning when postmodernists themselves agree with the criticism, such as being radical, overblown, absurd, irreverent, antirational, and even occult. They viewed these things as features. This answer borders on [and here he deploys euphemism] revisionism."

Comment: Your response to @Just Some Old Man was "I think you're conflating all this with DaDa. Regardless, it would be useful to know what specifically you're referring to, if only to separate it from serious philosophical efforts."   Yet are clearly aware of and have likely perused Francois Lyotard's The PostModern Condition: A Report on Knowledge, and Michel Foucault's Archeology of Knowledge.  These books, as you well know, were not concerned with aesthetics.  They were focused on knowledge, and truth.  And they had a PROFOUND effect upon the type of "meaning" which is the subject of this query.

Comment: @gonzo: I don't disagree with what you say about Lyotard and Foucault. I just don't see how it has anything to do with the existence or nonexistence of a philosophical school called 'postmodernism'.  Foucault and Lyotard were profound philosophers, they just weren't profound *postmodernist* philosophers any more than Newton and Einstein were (let's say) brilliant *gregorian* physicists. Just because the words 'gregorian' and 'postmodernist' exists as labels in English doesn't mean we can apply them willy-nilly to whatever and whomever we like.

Comment: @gonzo: to the other point: Likewise, *I* only know what *you* post here, and your posts to me are usually laced with insults, insinuations, and personal comments that have nothing to do with the intellectual content under discussion, and speak clearly to personal animus. If you don't want me to think that, the solution is simple: don't write that way.

Comment: C,mon, Ted, are you[!!?] now making some sort of metaphysical/semantical "essentialist" claim that there is "no such thing"...[as a] category/class of philosopher folk ("philosophical school") that can usefully (and, BTW, accurately) be characterized as postmodernists"?  That the term has no meaning?  Yet you also claim that these dudes, Lyotard and Foucault,  simply were not “profound postmodernist philosophers."   Which, I need not point out, is profoundly incoherent.   For how can one aptly engage in a fach that does not exist.

Comment: And this is what led me to comment upon your "answer" in the first place, and in part what led to @Just Some Old Man, saying that you are a "revisionist" :  That the first sentence of your post was "First, let's be clear: postmodernism (as such) does not exist, except in certain branches of aesthetics (fine art, architecture, perhaps literature...)."  And in response you claim that he is mistaking the concept "postmodernisn," with the early 20th century artistic movement of "DaDa"?!"    You could not have been more [sophistically] uncharitable (see D.Davidson) to the "old man."

Comment: As to your second comment.  I am simply not as proficient as you at discrediting others endeavors.  Again, to @Just Some Old, after claiming that he was simply confusing da da with postmodernism (which "in fact" either does not exist, or is limited to "profound postmodernism")   you say "it would be useful to know what specifically you're referring to, if only to separate it from serious philosophical efforts"   [read: unlike your own facile efforts].

Comment: @gonzo: JustSomeOldMan's comment was more or less a straw-man argument against modern European philosophy, which really did sound like he was describing the DaDa movement. Your commentary is more or less incomprehensible. You seem to be asserting that Derrida and Foucault are postmodernists *a priori*, despite the fact that neither they nor anyone else in the philosophical community regularly describes them as such. And I don't care if you try to discredit *my arguments*: arguments are presented to the world to be challenged. I get annoyed when you try to discredit *me*. Differentiate.

Comment: @gonzo: flagged as unkind (for the first four words; I told you not to comment on me as a person). And I ignored your critique because it's logically impossible to prove that something *oes not* exist. The burden is on you to prove that 'postmodernism' is an actual functional school or category of philosophy (outside of aesthetics).

Comment: Here you go:  Why do you simply ignore criticism (my first two comments) that you cannot dismiss glibly. I am not talking haphazardly about "Foucault and Derrida", I am addressing, specifically, Lyotard's PM Condition's use of the term "postmodern" to describe "the condition of knowledge" over the 20th c as a "crisis of narratives," as "incredulity toward metanarratives" [which of course are are the primary meaning generators], And to Foucault's characterization of meaning as simply a discursively created artifact deployed by the powerful to oppress the powerless.

Comment: @gonzo: Yes Lyotard coined the term 'postmodern'. It's an interesting and useful word, But the use of a word does not imply the creation of a school of thought. Why are we still talking about this?

Comment: The situation is akin to case in ancient Greece, where  pyrrhic skepticism yielded either stoicism or sophism.  The first, quietism -- or simply shutting up.   For why, in the absence of a quest for power, money  and/or influence (sophism in business or academia) claim to know what one knows what cannot be known?  The metaphysical void left by the death of god, expanded by postmodern universal epistemic skepticism/nihilism, led to either strict laissez faire neolibism or the popularly described sophistic neolibism, as described in the OP's quoted as The Perverse Art of Destroying Meaning.

Comment: We are still talking because you led your answer with "First, let's be clear: postmodernism (as such) does not exist, except in certain branches of aesthetics (fine art, architecture, perhaps literature...).   And I simply wanted to make sure that your more impressionable  readers, understood what you meant by those words.

Comment: @gonzo: Well, I'm sure you clarified things for them...

Comment: @TedWrigley It seems like you very much want the term “postmodernism” to mean nothing or only something disparaging in all contexts, when it is quite a common term used in philosophical and cultural contexts to help indicate certain philosophies and a movement. It is commonly used in humanities classes (I’m in a position to know this). Your position doesn’t make sense concerning the amount of simply descriptive literature there is on the topic. Just because a term describes a movement, and that movement is criticized, does not mean the term means nothing or is only disparaging.

Comment: @JustSomeOldMan: I think at this point you and/or gonzo should write your own answers, in which you can explain your positions in any detail you care to. I don't see the relevance of most of your comments, and find parts completely incomprehensible, so there is no real reason to continue this discussion in comments. If you have **specific** and **detailed** revisions you would like me to consider, please offer those. Anything else you should keep to yourself or develop into a full and independent answer (which I will carefully avoid commenting on). Thanks for your consideration in advance.